# Float is truncated in the gui after table binding

Tags: java, swing, bind

I use table binding as folows

```
final JTableBinding<rowModel, List<rowModel>, JTable> indexTB = 
   SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(
       AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, rowModels, indexTable);
```

and I bind with

```
indexTB.addColumnBinding(amount).setColumnName("Amount").setColumnClass(Float.class).setEditable(useConstAmounts);
```

and my bean property is

```
 MyBeanPropertyImpl amount = MyBeanPropertyImpl.create(rowModel.class, "amount", Float.class);
```

In the gui - the amount column in the table gets truncated to three digits after the dot (i.e. 95.123) and I need more digits.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have added `setConverter(new Converter(10))` as follows:

```
indexTB.addColumnBinding(amount).setColumnName("Amount").setColumnClass(Float.class)
    .setEditable(useConstAmounts).setConverter(new Converter(10))
```